# other multiselect options getting selected when I click on 'Select All' of one multiselect box

Tags: angularjs, select, multi-select

This is a strange behavior I am facing in my HTML form, As I said **when I click on one 'multiselect' box 'Select All' option the other 'multiselect' box all options getting selected** and the current 'multiselect' box options not getting selected. My code is in angularjs. Below is my code.

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
    <div ng-class="!isEmpty(resultData)?'col-md-12 text-left':'col-md-2'">
        <label class="form-label">EMPLOYMENT TYPE</label>
    </div>
    <div ng-class="!isEmpty(resultData)?'col-md-12':'col-md-10'">
        <multiselect  name="employment_type" class="form-control" multiple="true" ng-model="AdvanceSearch['search1']['employment_type']" options='cs.name for cs in MY_EMPLOYEMENT_TYPES' change="selected()" ng-required="field.is_required" ></multiselect>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
    <div ng-class="!isEmpty(resultData)?'col-md-12 text-left':'col-md-2'">
        <label class="form-label">WORK AUTHORIZATION</label>
    </div>
    <div ng-class="!isEmpty(resultData)?'col-md-12':'col-md-10'">
        <multiselect  name="work_auth" class="form-control" multiple="true" ng-model="AdvanceSearch['search1']['work_auth']" options='cs.name for cs in MY_WORK_AUTHORIZATION' change="selected()" ng-required="field.is_required" ></multiselect>

    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
    <div ng-class="!isEmpty(resultData)?'col-md-12 text-left':'col-md-2'">
        <label class="form-label">Languages</label>
    </div>
    <div ng-class="!isEmpty(resultData)?'col-md-12':'col-md-10'">
        <multiselect  name="languages" class="form-control" multiple="true" ng-model="AdvanceSearch['search1']['languages']" options='cs.name for cs in MY_LANGUAGES_LIST' change="selected()" ng-required="field.is_required" ></multiselect>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Suppose in my case, If I click on 'Languages' selectAll option then above multiselect options getting selected**.  I don't know Does anyone faced this problem before or not..! Why I am facing this unexpected behavior..! Whats wrong in my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please share your javascript with us? What does the `selected()` function do?

Comment: I will post give me some time.